# Installing gpc on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, ubuntu-14.04, gpc

I am trying to install the gpc (5:2.1-4.1.2-43ubuntu1) on the ubuntu 14.01, but it continues to say:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    gpc-4.1 : Depends: gcc-4.1 (>= 4.1.2-2) but it is not going to be installed

But when I use `gcc --version`, it shows my gcc version is 4.8.2 and I use `dpkg --get-selections | grep gcc`, it shows gcc-4.8, gcc-4.8-base:amd64 and gcc-4.9-base:amd64 are all installed. And when I try to install gcc-4.1 to meet its dependency, it always failed.

Any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: I don't believe you can use that version of gpc. I would recommend you use `fpc` which is [freepascal](http://freepascal.org/).

Comment: Yes. Its not in gcc anymore because they stopped to support it and now it works only with older gcc versions so I suppose its not guaranteed that new gcc supports gpc.

Answer (score 0):

ppa versions of the GNU Pascal Compiler for Ubuntu can be downloaded from here https://launchpad.net/~ueter/+archive/ubuntu/gpc-3.4

PB
[pascal](/questions/tagged/pascal)